# 1D Texture lookup table with fixed function pipeline

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, lookup-tables, texture1d

I want to create a 1D texture with OpenGL's (old) fixed function pipeline, which interpolated through three colors.

After looking online: `glTexImage1D` is commonly referred to. I cannot find any good simple sample codes for this, and I wouldn't know how to return a (RGB) value from this.

Does OpenGL (fixed function) have any methods for creating a 1D Texture, and returning an RGB value from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, [`glTexImage1D()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexImage1D.xml) + `GL_TEXTURE_1D`:

[image: screenshot of a 3-colored triangle]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint tex = 0;
void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_1D );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex );
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glTexCoord1f( 0.0f );
    glVertex2f( -0.5f, -0.5f );
    glTexCoord1f( 0.5f );
    glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f );
    glTexCoord1f( 1.0f );
    glVertex2f( 0.0f, 0.5f );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 400, 400 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glewInit();

    glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex );
    unsigned char pixels[] =
    {
        255, 0, 0, 255,
        0, 255, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 255, 255,
    };
    glTexImage1D( GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA, 3, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );
    glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would there be any way, in the display() being able to return an RGB value from, for example `glTexCoord1f()`. This is nearly exactly I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tester: Kinda: make a 1x1 FBO, render a `GL_POINTS` with your target texture coordinate, and then use `glReadPixels()` to grab the color value.  Not very efficient though.  Definitely feels like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory.  Why do you want to use OpenGL to grab the RGB value of a given texture coordinate instead of interpolating the values yourself CPU-side?

Comment: Sorry, i'll give more detail. I'm using `glDrawElements` to render my objects. I wish to store an array of colors, to pass to this. So for each vertex, I would want to lookup its color from a 1D texture, relating to its height.

Comment: @tester: Same idea then: with the same 1D texture creation/binding code use `glTexCoordPointer()` with `size` set to `1` & an appropriate vertex array/vertex buffer of texture coordinates.

Comment: I'm using your creation/binding code, then `glTexCoordPointer(1, GL_FLOAT, 0, tArray)` where `tArray` is an array of normalised floats between 0-1, relating to the height of the vertex. But the output is completely wrong. Any chance you could help?

Comment: @tester: Sure, spin up a new question with a [mcve] and I'll take a look.